# Type 'File | File[]' is not assignable to type 'string | string[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, formidable

I'm parsing a form in a Next.js api file using the npm package formidable-serverless. I'm trying to move the data from "fields" and "files" into one data object that I can add to my database but I'm getting a typescript error.

My code looks like:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import formidable from 'formidable-serverless'
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
import { Fields, Files } from 'formidable'
const Database = require("@replit/database")
const db = new Database()

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
}

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  return new Promise<void> ((resolve, reject) => {

    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
    
    form.parse(req, (err: Error, fields: Fields, files: Files) => {
       if (err) {
       res.status(422).end()
       } else {
          const data = fields
          data.address = JSON.parse(data.address as string)
          data.logo = files.logo
          const id = nanoid()
          db.set(id, data)
              .then(() => {
              res.status(201).end()
              resolve()
              })
              .catch(() => {
                  res.status(500).end()
                  resolve()
              })
```

The error is for data.logo and says "Type 'File | File[]' is not assignable to type 'string | string[]'." I tried to add an interface for the data object like so:

```
interface Data {
  name: string;
  address: string;
  logo: File | File[]
}
```

I then created a data object

```
const data = {
  name: fields.name,
  address: fields.address,
  logo: files.logo
} as Data
```

but got this error: "Conversion of type '{ name: string | string[]; address: string | string[]; logo: formidable.File | formidable.File[]; }' to type 'Data' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. "

I am new to Typescript and am unsure of what else I can try to fix this. Can anyone please help?

Comment: The question is not self-contained, as currently written, so we can't be sure that we guess correctly. What's `Fields`, `File` and `Files` here, at the very least?

Comment: I just updated the post to show my whole file! I believe fields and files is how formidable refers to the form data that it parsed. Inside of fields is the data for "name" and "address" and inside of files is data from a logo image uploaded by the user.